# JPA queries with several conditions?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, playframework

I'm working on a small game using the Play framework and JPA. I've read [their documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/jpa), and most of it is quite clear, but I really don't understand how to combine conditions, especially with one of the values that I want to check, being a boolean.

My User class has an online datamember:

```
public online;
```

I'm using a mysql database and this column is saved as a bit(1).
What I want to do is fetch a list of all the users that are online `(online = true)` and are also in a specific room.

I know how to do the second part, but I don't know how to check if online is set to true or not in the database.

This is what I have:

```
List<User> userList = User.find("byRoom", room).fetch();
```

How do I check for the online status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Their simplified query API suggests that you should be able to use something like: `User.find("byRoomAndOnline", room, 1).fetch()`.

Otherwise, you can use a something more JPA-ish query: `User.find("room = ? and online = 1", room).fetch()`